# Scipy Blas/Lapack: Force use of AVX instruction set

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, cython, lapack, blas

I've written a simple cython program using scipy.linalg.cython_blas. When profiling the code, I see that the blas routines such as dgemv and dgemm are using the SSE instruction set. Given that my system supports both AVX and AVX2, is it possible for me to force the use of the AVX instruction set?

How if possible or why not if not possible?

System Configuration:

1. Intel Coffeelake architecture: 4cores
2. Os: CentOs7
3. Python 3.8.5
4. Cython 0.29.23
5. Scipy 1.5.3
6. libblas.so.3.4.2

Thanks

Comment: This is likely defined by the lapack library you link to

Comment: The instructions to use are decided by the blas library. You are probably using a too old blas which does not have the best kernels for your CPU. Or perhaps you are trying to use intel's MKL on and amd CPU.